# Offline collaborative whiteboard/sketchboard

Tags: offline, collaboration, drawing, whiteboard

I'm looking for an offline/self-host collaborative whiteboard/sketchboard software to use on my company.

We have a need for it to be off the internet since we do some fun excursions sometimes.

Something like http://www.sketchboard.io but doesn't need to be as good/complex as it.

- Any operational system will do.

Comment: For what Operating System?

Comment: Any will do, but Windows is preferred.

Comment: Has this question found an answer yet?

Comment: Not until this moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [**Ziteboard** – an online whiteboard](https://ziteboard.com) with real-time collaboration running on any device with any OS. It is a web app, means it uses [pure html5 + javascript](https://ziteboard.com/faq/), so it is cross-platform software. The UI is minimal, the working space is maximal.

[image]

**Offline**: an app can't be offline and collaborative in the same time. However Ziteboard works well if no internet connection. Collaborators can draw offline and all drawings will be synced after reconnection.

**Self-host**: Ziteboard doesn't offer on-premise solution, but something close: true [white label solution](https://ziteboard.com/white-label-online-whiteboard-api/). The app can be customized to your brand and needs. The service runs under your domain and can be embedded into your page, web app.