# Collaborative Whiteboard

Tags: whiteboard

I used AwwApp for a long time but around a week ago it has been shut down in favor of Miro which, however, requires a registration. So I am searching for a replacement with the following features:

1. no fees and no need for registration, it can also be self hosted (I do have a RasPi with a subdomain linked to it), open source projects preferred
2. possibility of erasing full strokes (rather than just the portions directly under the cursor)
3. possibility of inserting images
4. integrated chat

I already tried:

- WBO (lacking 2., 3. and 4.)
- Excalidraw (lacking 3. and 4., also there is no eraser tool, you need to select a stroke with the select tool to delete it)
- Miro (lacking 1.)
- Whitebird (lacking 4. and having problems with rudimentary tools like missing straight line and eraser tool)
- Spacedeck (installation fails)
- Ziteboard (lacking 1.)

Comment: Have a look at the list of related questions (on the right). Is [this answered question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/24994/offline-collaborative-whiteboard-sketchboard) not helpful? (NB: I haven't tried it)

Comment: The only answer proposes Ziteboard. I added it to the list above now, unfortunately, it is not free though otherwise it looks very promising. Most of the other questions are quite old (4-6 years old), I couldn't find anything suiting so far, but I probably should document it by extending the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been advised to use [Conceptboard](https://conceptboard.com). It requires a registration but offers all the necessary features in the free plan and, most importantly, a registered user can invite guest users without them being forced to register as well.

Other than that, I found out that WBO actually does have a proper erase tool (2.) , so it only lacks the chat and insert images functionality. I will keep an eye on it and possibly switch if those features will be implemented at some point.